# Visual Studio 2022: Java related issues when user name contains non ASCII characters in Xamarin Android Development

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, javac

I've created a new Xamarin Android project on Visual Studio 2022. Code and designer works properly. I wanted to deploy the app to the Android Emulator. First I have problem with "file doesn't exists: xxx.tmp" error and I assumed this is about the non ascii characters of my user name "Özkan..." and changed my temp dir to C:\Temp.

After trying again to deploy, now I have a compile error:

```
Error       Error in C:\Users\Özkan\.nuget\packages\xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture\1.0.0.2\buildTransitive\monoandroid50\guava-listenablefuture.jar:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Özkan\.nuget\packages\xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture\1.0.0.2\buildTransitive\monoandroid50\guava-listenablefuture.jar
```

However I've checked the "C:\Users\Özkan\.nuget\packages\xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture\1.0.0.2\buildTransitive\monoandroid50\guava-listenablefuture.jar" and it exists in it's location.

And bunch of some other files with the same kind of error.

Looks like java doesn't recognize the non ascii command line parameters / file paths. How can I overcome the problem_

Comment: You can try to create another demo with a simple name and see if such a problem persists.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT what do you mean by that? This is not the project name with non ANSI characters, my Windows user name.

Comment: You can try to change the location for your project.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT this is not about the location of the project, it is about my Windows user name. I've already changed the project location to c:\Somefolder, changed the location of the Temp folder to c:\Temp, I receive still the error above.

Comment: @OzkanTuzemen Has there been any fixes in the VS 2022 compiler for this issue ? If not what is the workaround you have found for this issue ?

Comment: @developer I have changed user name from registry and moved all files to the new directory with user name. Also could be done by creating a new user name but I didn't want to work on moving files and settings etc.